# Microsoft Explorer Edge same box shadow, two different result

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Gives a different result when you give the height value?
Am I missing something? Or is MS rendering that bad?

```css
.box {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.height-1{
  height:35px
}

.height-2{
  height:50px
}
```

```html
<div class="box height-1">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="box height-2">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

[Example Link](https://codepen.io/fatih-erol/pen/OoKLbB)

Comment: Please be clear whether you're referring to Internet Explorer 11, Microsoft Edge, or both. Don't lump their two names together carelessly, it's neither funny nor clever and only makes your question difficult to understand, let alone take seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with Edge and I got the similar result. Both boxes have same shadow.

Below is my testing result.

[image]

You mentioned 'Microsoft Explorer' in your title, so I also make a test with IE 11 and got the similar result.

[image]

So I am not able to produce the issue with above code. You can again try to make a test and if the issue still exist then try to post the picture of it.

Also try to inform us if we are missing any step while producing the issue.

We will try to correct ourselves and again try to make a test.

Comment: Hi. thx for answer. do you check the shadows in the first picture. both different.

Comment: As per my view, If you see the whole box and compare the both shadow then it looks same. You are using the different height for both boxes, So it is possible that because of that reason you think that shadow are different but both shadows are same.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT in your first screen shot, the shadows are different. The bottom appears thicker.